# 406 Not Acceptable error on live server - JSON

Tags: php, json, .htaccess, http-headers

I've just moved a site to live and am getting a 406 Not Acceptable error when using jquery to make an ajax request to a php script. I don't get the error on my test server so I'm just trying to figure out the correct way to fix this. The AJAX request is as follows, and expects JSON response, while my php script is just echoing out with `json_encode()`.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: "{}",
        url: "server/php/progress.php",
        dataType: "json",
```

EDIT: here's the crux of my php script (have also tried without the header setting):

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($val);
exit;
```

Any thoughts on what should be done to fix this? htaccess directives?

Comment: Maybe progress.php does not support `POST` requests?

Comment: try using data: {}, without "" and yes i assuming u closed your ajax method }); as well and check method too  ;)

Comment: thanks for the replies, but there are no script errors when running this on my local test server. something in the server config is causing the 406 error to be triggered, which is why I was thinking maybe htaccess content type rules

Comment: Did try to call your php script interactively from the browser - if your script is not able to accept GET requests you will need to write a small test page to POST to it? What is the result? More often than not it will display better error information.

Comment: If I access the php script from the browser, it correctly outputs the data I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aargh. Just switching it to GET sorted the issue. I'm not sure why on earth I was using POST for retrieval.

Still not sure why the issue didn't happen on my local wamp server, some difference in the apache settings somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Not acceptable will be triggered based on Accept, Accept-Charset, Accept-Language headers. So if your code is identical, it's likely that there's some setting related to content negotiation turned on there.