# Sending post-data with jquery produces 406 error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a form with a tinymce-textfield whose contents I send to a php-script using jQuery's $.post command.

This works fine in most cases, unless I have a form in that textfield (it is a PayPal-Donate form) that looks like this:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank"><input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_s-xclick" /> <input name="hosted_button_id" type="hidden" value="xxxxxx" /> <input alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" type="image" /> <img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" /></form>
<p><strong>Make a monthly donation</strong></p>
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank"><input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_s-xclick" /> <input name="hosted_button_id" type="hidden" value="xxxx" />
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><input name="on0" type="hidden" value="Make a monthly donation" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><select name="os0">
<option value="$10 Month">$10 Month : $10.00 USD - monthly</option>
<option value="$25 Month">$25 Month : $25.00 USD - monthly</option>
<option value="$35 Month">$35 Month : $35.00 USD - monthly</option>
<option value="$50 Month">$50 Month : $50.00 USD - monthly</option>
<option value="$100 Month">$100 Month : $100.00 USD - monthly</option>
<option value="$125 Month">$125 Month : $125.00 USD - monthly</option>
<option value="$140 Month">$140 Month : $140.00 USD - monthly</option>
<option value="$200 Month">$200 Month : $200.00 USD - monthly</option>
<option value="$250 Month">$250 Month : $250.00 USD - monthly</option>
<option value="$300 Month">$300 Month : $300.00 USD - monthly</option>
</select></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input maxlength="200" name="os1" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="USD" /> <input alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" type="image" /> <img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" /></form>
```

Oddly enough, it works on my local webserver. But when I put it on the live-server, it produces said 406-error…

Any ideas?

[Edit]

Here's the javascript:

```
var serial = $('#frmPageEdit').serialize();

serial = serial + "&fid_navigation=" + id + "&action=save_page";

$.post('pages.html', serial, function(data){

            var result = _pagesSplitResponse(data);
            // Do some stuff with the response here...

            window.alert(_pagesTranslations['seite_gespeichert']);
}
```

Again - it works fine with all the other content, it's just the form above that causes the error...

Comment: Please show your Javascript.

Comment: posted the js in the edit

Comment: Try switching it to a `GET` request. The PHP script may not support `POST`. Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645844/406-not-acceptable-error-on-live-server-json

Comment: Well, it does support POST. I wrote the PHP script and it is successfully working with other content. I did track it down to this form. When I remove the form from the content, the script happily accepts the POST-data and does what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, it was some XSS-mechanism on the server that caused the error. Don't know exactly which part of the form caused the error, but I suspect it was the input-fields.

For anybody who runs into the same problem, here's the solution:

Use some kind of base_64-encoding for your form-vars that are causing the trouble before submitting it (like this one: https://github.com/carlo/jquery-base64 for jQuery) and then in base_64-decode it in the receiving PHP-script.

One thing that caused some trouble doing this was that I'm using tinyMCE as an editor, which added a

…

around the base_64 encoded string. Decoding first failed because of this. So make sure you strip every HTML-element off the encoded string before decoding it.

Hope it helps anyone